# How to deploy to App Engine from web

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket, google-cloud-platform, codeanywhere

I hope someone can help-me.

I'm trying to move my development workflow to the web, so I would not need to install anything locally.

To accomplish it I'm using codeanywhere and storing my code on bitbucket, which is connected with my project´s cloud platform.

Everything is working fine, I make a change on codeanywhere commit it on bitbucket and see the change on my project's source code (on the cloud plataform). But the changes are not reflected on my application (the actual source code running my application isn't updated).

I'm running out of alternatives, I tried to update it using the Cloud Platform's Cloud Shell but I couldn't even cd to the source code folder.

Does anyone know how to deploy the source code from the Cloud Plataform to App Engine?

I need a full online workflow.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Use push to deploy? https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html

Comment: Are you trying to get a continuous deployment workflow working? What did you try from Cloud Shell? You should be able to `git clone/pull` your repo and then use `gcloud app deploy ...` to deploy.

Comment: My first goal was a continuos deployment workflow.
First I tried to use the Cloud Shell as I would on my local command line, cd to the project folder (source code on the Cloud Shell) and run "appcfg.py update app.yaml", but I wasn't able to find the source code folder on Cloud Shell. After that I tried to git clone but it didn't work(got the following error: Permission denied (publickey).fatal: Could not read from remote repository.).

Comment: I use Cloud Shell daily and it comes with git, gcloud, etc. already installed. Git clone definitely works and once you have your code, you can use gcloud app deploy to deploy it to App Engine. I suggest you take a look at one of the Quickstarts and go through it from Cloud Shell. Maybe it can point out what you might be doing wrong. For example, this one is quite simple to go through: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You can use [source-repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/how-to) of GAE to keep source code and run application from shell for example running application `gradle appengineRun` & deploy application `gradle gradleappengineUpdate` using gradle

You can see [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) for building, running and deploying application using maven.

Comment: Maven seems to do everything I want, but I was looking on the docs and it is only for Java. My application runs in python (Sorry I forgot to mention it). Do you know something like Maven for python

Comment: I found this link:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/local-devserver-command  , using `dev_appserver.py .` development server can be started in python.

Comment: Also this site shows using maven with python but not sure how it'll work out in appengine environment-https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/building-python-packages-with-maven